# How to add extra values in one attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add so many values in one attribute. Below is my code,

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        XmlElement mainelement;
        mainelement = doc.CreateElement("main_element");
        root.AppendChild(mainelement);
        string[] array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            XmlElement subelement = doc.CreateElement("shop");
            subelement.SetAttribute("Name", "");
            subelement.SetAttribute("client", array[i]);
            mainelement.AppendChild(subelement);
        }
         doc.Save(@"C:\simple.xml");
```

It gives output like,

```
<root>
  <main_element>
    <shop Name="" client="one" />
    <shop Name="" client="two" />
    <shop Name="" client="three" />
  </main_element>
</root>
```

but my expected output is

```
<root>
  <main_element>
    <shop Name="" client="one,two,three" />
  </main_element>
</root>
```

help me for do changes like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer by @empereur-aiman is right. But in an XML perspective maybe you should use a format like this to be able to process it after:
`<root>
  <main_element>
    <shop Name="">
      <client id="one" />
      <client id="two" />
      <client id="three" />
    </shop>    
  </main_element>
</root>`

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string with the value of the attribute and assign it.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
doc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement mainelement;
mainelement = doc.CreateElement("main_element");
root.AppendChild(mainelement);

string[] array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
XmlElement subelement = doc.CreateElement("shop");
subelement.SetAttribute("Name", "");

string clientAttribute = String.Join(",",array);

subelement.SetAttribute("client", clientAttribute);
mainelement.AppendChild(subelement);
doc.Save(@"C:\simple.xml");
```

`String.Join` concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.
Here the separator is ",".